# How to build a collection of one-to-many entities without persisting parent entity to database first?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Not sure if I'm completely missing something but, I have a typical MVC web application using EF and role based authentication, as such:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Role> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<User> RoleUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally, in the above case, I would like a single edit screen to update a users name that also allows add/delete operations on the users roles, e.g. a form with an input field for the name, a table of the users roles with each row having a delete button, and a role drop down list with an add button.

How would I perform edits on the views model (User) without persisting the role additions/deletions to the database until a save request is issued?

It may be best to think of an Add operation instead. If inserting a new user, how could you build a collection of that users roles without inserting the user first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you're creating a user as a new instance of user, right? and a user has a list of UserRoles?

Comment: The model is strange, `IEnumerable<T>` cannot be a navigation property and you don't use the class `UserRole` in any of the relationships. Are you really using this model?

Comment: would it not be better if (going off the classes) a User had a LIST of UserRoles, and a UserRole related to a Role?

Comment: Sorry, the code is purely an example I wrote in the text editor - I presumed that would be OK as it's more advice I'm after. Assume the UserRoles and RoleUsers collections are Lists and forget the UserRole class (I'll do an edit).

Comment: Having said that, you're right @Slauma in a real-world application, both `UserRoles` and `RoleUsers` would be navigation properties (`EntityCollection<T>`).

Comment: Isn't a static list of check boxes with all possible roles an option for you? Adding and deleting entries in the web view is more complex, you would either do it with Javascript on client side (preferred solution I'd say, but dependent on enabled JS in brwoser) or have to handle the add/delete button post actions in the controller appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Slauma, but not in this particular case, the amount of options would make the page unmanageable.

I was hoping there would be some method using multiple forms. Each forms action relating to an add/delete operation but, somehow persist the views Model in each form.

But I'm guessing this isn't really possible?

It is an internal application so Javascript is probably the best choice. I may just assume that and change the action of the form with each submit add/delete button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this a bit more, Phil Haacked wrote an article on binding a view model to a list, found here...

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

I could probably have used this approach to have a single form with inputs for the entity properties and a collection of associated inputs bound using the above method for sub objects. Although I imagine this would probably require a duplicate list property for each navigation property on the parent entity, which is a strike for me.

If adding an entity with a collection of complex objects, this method also doesn't resolve how you might elegantly input all the properties for a complex object on the same view (as the parent entity only exists in memory) - the simplest approach probably being partial views containing the edit forms?

For simplicity, I opted to change the edit view to only edit the basic properties of the entity and have a separate link for sub objects that redirects to the relevant controller, using the User example, an add operation would follow as such:

- User/Edit/{user_id} view -> Input the users name, email etc.
- Click Save -> Redirect to User/Index or User/Details/{user_id}
- A 'manage roles' link is available for this user, once clicked -> Redirect to /Role/Index/{user_id}
- Page displays a table of roles for this user with the ability to add/edit etc.

**Edit:**

Also, in case this helps anyone else.

I set the `/Role/Index` action to list all roles by default, however it also accepts a UserId parameter (`/Role/Index/{user_id}`). When a UserId is specified, the action returns a different view (`/Role/IndexForUser`) whose data model is the `User` entity - it does the same as the default `Index` view, but only lists roles associated with the user, and displays more contextual links such as 'remove user from role'.